# About the proof of invertible quadratic expressions in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

The theorem is that if $ T\in L(V)$ (and $V$ is a real finite-dimensional vector space) is self-adjoint and b,c $\in \mathbb R$ such that $b^2<4c$. Then the operator $$ T^2 + bT +cI$$ is invertible.
The proof is

> $\langle  (T^2+bT+cI)v,v\rangle = \|Tv\|^2+c\|v\|^2+\langle bTv,v\rangle \\ \geq \|Tv\|^2+c\|v\|^2-|b|\|Tv\|\cdot\|v\| =(\|T\|-\dfrac{|b|}{2}\|v|)^2+\|v\|^2(c-\dfrac{b^2}{4})>0$

> (The inequality is by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

However, (this might be a silly question) I don't know why we can't regard the operator  $$ T^2 + bT +cI$$ as a quadratic function in terms of $T$. Then by using the discriminant $\Delta= b^2 -4c$, the answer will show up immediately.

Is this forbidden due to $T$ being an operator? Or is it possible to consider all the operators on $V$  to be an infinite-dimensional vector space $W$ and there exists a map $S$ such that $S: W\to W, T \to T^2+bT+cI$. Then use the discriminant?

Comment: Well, it is a quadratic function of $T$ but I do not understand what you mean by the answer will show up immediately?

Comment: You wrote *“the answer will show up immediately”*. Would you please show us how?

Comment: Is $V$ assumed finite dimensional?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not mentioning the finite dimension and this is on the real vector space. My idea is that if regard $T$ is the variable in quadratic function $T^2+bT+cI$. Then, just like other quadratic functions, by the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4c$. Then due to $b^2<4c$, this implies $\Delta<0$ which means that $T^2+bT+cI>0$ forever(since a= 1>0, this quadratic function is convex)

Comment: This argument makes a superficial sense when you pay attention only to the choice of notation: addition, scalar multiplication, and squaring of operators is notated exactly the same way as with real numbers. I'm not sure if you know this, but $T^2 + bT + cI > 0$ does have a meaning too, which is that $T^2 + bT + cI$ is positive-definite. But, these operations/inequalities mean something different to their real counterparts, so the discriminant result needs to be proven in this setting, with these different operations/relations... which is the purpose of the proof in Axler.

Comment: So you mean that considering the discriminant is a reasonable idea, but since this case is concerning operators which are not real numbers, the "meaning" of the $\Delta=b^2-4c<0$ should be proved and this is what the author did in the book.  Thus if my proof is just " since $\Delta=b^2-4c<0 $, $ T^2+bT+cI>0 $". This is wrong since my proof becomes something that is needed to be proved. And the right proof should be something like $\Delta=b^2-4c<0 \implies \cdots \implies   T^2+bT+cI>0 $. Is this right?

Comment: @Yink Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me how the proof above is meant to work, perhaps it is assumed that $V$ is finite dimensional?

If $V$ is any Hilbert space then the result is true. The following proof depends on the fact that a normal operator $A$ is invertible **iff** it is bounded below (that is, there is some $\mu>0$ such that $\|Ax\| \ge \mu \|x\|$).

Let $u\pm iv$ solve $x^2+bx+c=0$ (in particular, since $b^2<4c$ we see that $v \neq 0$) and note that
$T+bT+cI = (T-uI-ivI)(T-uI+ivI)$. It is straightforward to check that $B=T-uI- ivI$ is normal and we see that $T+bT+cI = B B^*$.

$\|Bx\|^2 = \langle Bx, Bx \rangle = \|(T-u)x\|^2 + |v^2|\|x\|^2 \ge |v|^2 \|x\|^2$ and so $B$ is invertible. Similarly $B^*$ is invertible and so $BB^*$ is invertible.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $T^2 + bT + cI = 0$ and proving $T$ is invertible. The question is about concluding that $T^2 + bT + cI$ is invertible, under the given discriminant assumption.

Comment: @TheoBendit Urrgh, thanks, I was.

Comment: Rectified my egregious earlier answer.